# has anyone got selective sync working on dropbox for linux?

Tags: ubuntu, sync, dropbox

I like the selective sync function on dropbox and I've got it working for dropbox 1.0 on my Mac and PC but i can't get it going for Linux. All the versions for Linux are version 0.6 without all the current features, and with a few bugs as well. But I swear I got selective sync working on linux a few months ago (before I lost the machine it was on), so they must have had a more recent linux version a while ago. Are the files on the website wrong or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do these following steps:

- Shutdown your dropbox with GUI or CLI

`$ dropbox stop` (if CLI)

- Run package update for ***nautilus-dropbox***

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get upgrade nautilus-dropbx`

- Start your dropbox again

`$ dropbox start`

Now enjoy the new Dropbox features.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the CLI to exclude the folder I don't want to sync:

```
dropbox exclude add FOLDERNAME
```

Afterwards, to control everything, run

```
dropbox exclude list
```

On Fedora29, I don't have the "classical" Dropbox client running.